# Stored procedure to create view with dynamic ID based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, view

I have a little problem with creating view based on another table.

My first approach was to create variable and assign length of the table to variable, then create view and in loop insert dynamically ID column based on length and add the second column with Name.

But I got stuck and don't know how to code it

My pseudo-code is

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE <name>
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @len_table INT = (SELECT Count(*) 
                              FROM dbo.table_1);

    DECLARE @counter INT = 0;

    EXEC ('CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT Name FROM dbo.table_1')

    WHILE @counter < len_table
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO MyView
       SET id = @counter
       SET @counter = @counter + 1
    END
END
```

And this is how table_1 looks like:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cat |
| 3 | dog |
| 4 | snake |
| 2 | monkey |

My goal is to get id based on length of column Name like this

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cat |
| 2 | monkey |
| 3 | dog |
| 4 | snake |

I will appreciate any way of help.

If someone could link good resources about T-SQL, also it'll be awesome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't see how you want to map `3`, `6`, `3`, `5` (the lengths of the `Name` values) to `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` as inside diameters (`ID`). Could you expound on the algorithm? It looks more like you just want the results ordered by `ID`, something a [`view`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#as) can't do.

Comment: Confused by what you are trying to do here - a view is literally just a wrapper for the query you define - what are you supposed to be inserting in your procedure?

Comment: Maybe I wrote this wrong, but what I want is to get the ID ascending based on a column Name - if column name has 6 rows in table_1 I want to have ID 1,2,3,4,5,6 in view

Comment: Dynamically create a column ID, if for example someone add new row to table_1 i want to add it dynamically to view

Comment: This doesn't really make sense - "length of column name" - do you mean the length of the _value_? If so why is cat #1, monkey #2, dog #3, and snake #4? The lengths of those strings: 3, 6, 3, 5.

Comment: A `view` can't produce an ordered result set, though a query that references the view can sort it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like Row_Number() is what you are looking for. Try using this to create your view.

```
CREATE view myView AS
SELECT Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY ID) ID, Name
FROM dbo.table_1
```

Comment: That will produce _dense_ `ID` output values, i.e. it preserves the order of the input `ID` values and starts counting from `1` but "fixes" any "missing" values, but it does not guarantee the order of the rows in the result.